# No clue... Is the specialised default argument confused the template type deduction?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, c++-chrono

The code provided below failed to compile. The compiler blames `candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'Rep2'`. What I expect is to provide a d1 and use the default value as d2.

Is it due to the default value `d2=std::chrono::minutes(1)` which confused the type deduction? However, the default is the second argument which is the desired default as there is no 2nd argument provided in the `BAr bar{...}` statement.

```
#include<chrono>

struct Bar
{
  std::chrono::nanoseconds duration1;
  std::chrono::nanoseconds duration2;

  Bar()=delete;
  template<class Rep,class Period,class Rep2,class Period2>
  Bar(
      const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> &d1,
      const std::chrono::duration<Rep2, Period2> &d2=std::chrono::minutes(1)):
      duration1(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(d1)),
      duration2(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(d2))
  {
  }
};

int main()
{
  Bar bar{std::chrono::hours(7)};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link... so, is it not a good idea to provide a default value for the template arguments in general? For this problem, I can think of the ways to avoid the error by providing 2 ctor: ` Bar(d1);` which initialize `duration2` to the default value, and the other ctor `Bar(d1,d2);` has no default argument.

Comment: No you just need to add defaults for `Rep2` and `Period2`

Comment: As your question is already marked as answered I will add my remarks as a comment.
`std::chrono::duration` allows for implicit casts to a smaller unit as there is no loss of information.
In your example, there is no need to use templates at all as std::chrono::nanoseconds is the smallest duration interval possible.

Check this example on godbolt: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EvRQcJ